# Change of Behavior of jQuery Starting with 1.9.0

Tags: jquery

The following code displays alert boxes containing "Radio1 Selected", "Radio2 Selected" or "Radio3 Selected" in response to click events on the radio buttons when version 1.8.3 of jQuery is used. However any versions after that displays "None Selected". Any ideas why?
Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function radioClicked(){
    if ($('#radio1').attr('checked') == 'checked') alert('Radio 1 Selected');
    else if ($('#radio2').attr('checked') == 'checked') alert('Radio 2 Selected');
    else if ($('#radio3').attr('checked') == 'checked') alert('Radio 3 Selected');
    else alert('None Selected');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="radio1">Radio 1</label><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" onclick="radioClicked()" />
<label for="radio2">Radio 2</label><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" onclick="radioClicked()" />
<label for="radio3">Radio 3</label><input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" onclick="radioClicked()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: radioClicked is not defined `.

Comment: What browser is giving the ReferenceError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if a checkbox is checked, you should be using `.is(':checked')`

```
function radioClicked(){
    if ($('#radio1').is(':checked')) alert('Radio 1 Selected');
    else if ($('#radio2').is(':checked')) alert('Radio 2 Selected');
    else if ($('#radio3').is(':checked')) alert('Radio 3 Selected');
    else alert('None Selected');
}
```

an easier way to check all checkboxes starting with "radio", would be:

```
function radioClicked(){
    $('[id^="radio"]').filter(':checked').each(function(i,ele) {
        alert(ele.id + ' is checked');
    })
}
```

And since they all have the same name and belong to the same group, only one radio can be checked, so you could even do:

```
function radioClicked(){
    alert( $('[name=radios]:checked').prop('id') + ' is checked');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very Elegant solutions in the second and third code segments. Unfortunately I have to stick with the original format of if's (but with the change you suggested) as I do other things instead of simply printing an alert message in the real code.